# How to give spacing between the content of view in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-stylesheet

I am new in react native,I have to view right and left container given flex-between them,
now I have to give space in contents of left and right container also.

image shown in the below diagram as well as styling code,

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: moderateScale(90),
    backgroundColor: "red",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  containerLeft: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    top: moderateScale(40),
    backgroundColor: "green",
    margin: moderateScale(12),
  },
  containerRightIcons: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    top: moderateScale(40),
    margin: moderateScale(12),
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: so you can give specific space to icon

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the individual child components inside a `View` and provide a `marginRight` when necessary. We could create a new component that handles this behaviour.

```js
export function Spacer({isHorizontal = true, space = 10, children}) {
    return <View style={isHorizontal ? {flexDirection: "row"} : null}>
        { 
            React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
                return index < children.length - 1 ? <View style={{marginRight: space}}>{child}</View> : child
            })
        }
    </View>
}
```

We use the `isHorizontal` flag to indicate whether the children are layed out in a row. The default value is set to `true` to satisfy your current design. However, we can reuse it for column based layouts as well. The default spacing is set to `10`. We can control it using the `space` prop.

Then, use it as follows.

```js
<Spacer>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
    <Child3 />
</Spacer>
```

We can control the space via props.

```js
<Spacer space={5}>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
    <Child3 />
</Spacer>
```